# How to run c++ program in mac terminal

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

I have installed c++4.9 in my mac, but compilation just terminated somehow. Could someone tell me why? thanks!
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575956/building-c-not-working-in-osx-10-9

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots.  Use plain text cut & pasted from your terminal window, so that future users can find this question if they search on the message you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the line above "compilation terminated." you get an explanation of why. `#include <wchar.h>` was the cause of the error: `wchar.h` could not be found. Please **read** the errors the compiler shows you.

Chances are you need to [reinstall the command-line tools](https://www.computersnyou.com/2025/install-command-line-tools-in-osx-10-9-mavericks-how-to/).

Comment: Alex, is more than likely right. Before embarking on a reinstallation, see if adding this file http://bit.ly/193dtQw to the folder your program is stored and then compiling helps. If you get another "*.h file is missing", it maybe related to a bad install. This video may help for installation instructions (for mavericks though) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ax0-h43_CVg

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the top of your terminal output (which actually prints the call to g++) is missing, but the directory that holds wchar.h is not being found. On my mac it is /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1. You can add the directory to your path:

```
> export PATH=$PATH:/user/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1
```

Or use a makefile that searches this path for headers.

Of course, you need to make sure you have this header in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://developer.apple.com and command line tools installer for Mavericks otherwise you can just type this in your terminal to install all the command line tools 
xcode-select --install