# fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

In my environment, I couldn't include `<cstring>`.
My g++ version is 4.9.3 (Homebrew gcc49 4.9.3).

The error is:

```
 - /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/cstring:42:20: fatal
   error: string.h: No such file or directory
  "#include string.h"
```

But, in another environment (g++ 4.8.4[Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3]), I can include `<cstring>` and run.

What's the problem and how do I solve it?

[P.S.]
Maybe, I misunderstood about the problem.
I tried to run my previous code, but got an error like this:

```
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/cassert:43:20: fatal error: assert.h: No such file or directory
 #include <assert.h>
```

Then, I can't run my code.
It is a g++'s problem.

I checked this article, but this procedure is not working.
I already installed xcode-select (commmad line tool) and I uninstalled xcode-select and reinstalled xcode-select, but it's not working.

[Building C++ not working in OSX 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575956/building-c-not-working-in-osx-10-9)

Comment: The problem is that you do not have C header files installed.

Comment: I think I installed Command Line(C header files).
I can find `/usr/include`.

Comment: Try `#include <string>`

Comment: I think <string> and <cstring> are certainly different.
But, I tried that. and I got another error.`/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/cwchar:44:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wchar.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the heaaders fixed my issue:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```