# Code::Blocks C++ compiling with MacOS Mojave : fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, compilation, codeblocks, math.h, macos-mojave

(This is my first question ever on StackOverflow)

I have to use a Mac at work, and I'm coding in C++ with Code::Blocks (because I am used to this IDE). 2 days ago I upgraded from MacOS High Sierra to MacOS Mojave and I can fairly say that... it was a bad decision.

Now, when trying to `#include <math.h>` I get this error : `fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory`. I have tried to reinstall the xcode line command tools with `xcode-select --install`, but it still doesn't work.

Does anybody have a clue of what is going on, and how I could solve this issue ?

Comment: have you tried to include cmath instead of math.h ? math.h is C not C++ cmath is the c++ equivalent (actually mostly a wrapper).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it absolutely does not change anything :(

Comment: have you tried using the search function is OSX to see if the file actually exists anywhere ? If yes, you could add the location path in Code::Blocks. If not you probaly need to get the headers installed with brew or the likes.

Comment: This is probably the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575956/building-c-not-working-in-osx-10-9 It appears that you have to download the cmd tools and install it rather then running xcode-slect --install.

Comment: Ok thanks for your replies. Thanks to what I read on them, I tried to reinstall gcc, and it solved the problem. The location of headers must have changed between High Sierra and Mojave.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling gcc. Location of headers has probably changed between High Sierra and Mojave.

I suggest to anyone encountering the same problem to do the same and also to (re)install the xcode line command tools with `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Reinstalling gcc4.9 and gcc7 had no effect for me. However, using a direct path (`/usr/bin/gcc`) allowed me to compile

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work for me, but [this did](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/21/compiling-gcc-macos/):

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
open .
```

and double clicking the pkg file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution :) I'm sad to hear that mine isn't working for everyone...