# 【MacOSX 10.15.1】Use odb generate database, fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory #include <wchar.h>

Tags: c++, odb

odb -d mysql --generate-query --generate-schema person.hxx

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/odb-2.4.0-i686-macosx/lib/odb/i686-apple-darwin10/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/postypes.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/odb-2.4.0-i686-macosx/lib/odb/i686-apple-darwin10/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/char_traits.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/odb-2.4.0-i686-macosx/lib/odb/i686-apple-darwin10/include/c++/4.9.3/string:40,
                 from <standard-odb-prologue>:7:
/usr/local/Cellar/odb-2.4.0-i686-macosx/lib/odb/i686-apple-darwin10/include/c++/4.9.3/cwchar:44:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wchar.h>
```

Comment: You should also share your code in `person.hxx`

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your XCode Command Line Tools like shown in [this link](https://www.computersnyou.com/2025/install-command-line-tools-in-osx-10-9-mavericks-how-to/) with

```
xcode-select --install
```

This helped me today with compiling a program with gcc-9 installed with brew on Mac OS X Catalina to which I updated yesterday.

Mac OS updates usually mess up the location of the headers, this may be your case, too.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575956/building-c-not-working-in-osx-10-9)

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the include directory of XCode command line tools by adding to your `odb` the following:

```
-I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

if this doesn't work, double check the path. Sometimes you would find the SDK directory is `MacOSX xx.xx.x` instead of `MacOSX.sdk`